# Lemma 2.2.1. Smith's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, proof-explanation

The following lemma from Smith's Algebraic Geometry book is *totally* not understandable :

[image]

For example :

1. How the degree $d$ of a more-than-one-variable polynomial is defined?
2. How the coefficient of $X^d_n$ is $f_d(λ_1, . . . , λ_{n-1}, 1)$?
3. How from $F$ being infinite, existence of some $f_d(λ_1, . . . , λ_{n-1},1)$ is concluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The degree is defined in monomials, for example $x^2y$ has degree 3, you have to sum all degres of the variable that apears in the monomial.
   Then the degree of a multi variable polynomial is the max degree that apear (as in normal polynomial). For example $f(x,y,z)=2x^2y-3xz+2z$ has degree 3.
2. What the autor did is group the terms of degree $d$, the same you will do in one variable polynomial, if $f(x)=3x^2+2x-x-x^2$ you will write $f(x)=(3-1)x^2+(2-1)x$. The autor do that with all monomials of degree $d$. So then when you evaluate the polynomial in the point $(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{n-1},1)$ you get an expression where instead of having $x^d$ you have the coeficient.
3. As $f_d$ is not identically null, necesary you will have a point in $F^{n-1}$ such that $f_d \neq 0$. The asumption in $F$ assures you that you have a copy of $F$ en $F[X_1, \cdots, F_n]$.

Hope this help you.